# Difference between what he is doing and what is he doing

Tags: grammaticality

May I know the difference between

> what he is doing

and

> what is he doing

Which is more correct?

Comment: This is more suitable for English Language Learners http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

"What he is doing" is a **phrase standing in for a noun**: if he is doing X, then "what he is doing" represents X, e.g. "I would like to see what he is doing" means I would like to see X.

"What is he doing" is a **question**, asking for the identity of X. The reversal of pronoun and verb makes the phrase interrogative.